# How are .libs created in your VS solution linked by another project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

If I have a project Foo that has a .lib as an output that's also used by projects Bar and Baz, how do I let Bar and Baz know where to find the library assuming MSVC? I have the project dependencies set up already, but how do I `#pragma comment(lib, "????/Foo.lib")` properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

Firstly, Visual Studio itself has a global library path that it searches for all projects. You can add directories to this via `Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > VC++ Directories > Library files`.

Alternatively, you can set the library path for specific projects. In the project properties set `Configuration Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Directories`.